# Como usar arquivos de recurso no arquivo XAML (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, xaml

Estou tentando utilizar aquivos de recurso no meu projeto Xamarin Forms mas não sei como referenciar a string do arquivo. Ex: `<Label Text="MyApp.Resources.MinhaString" />`.
Alguém sabe como fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siga o procedimento descrito em https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/ e acesse o arquivo de recursos usando a classe TranslateExtension.

Ex.: `<Button Text="{i18n:TranslateExtension Text=AddButton}" />`  ou para ficar menos verboso oculte a palavra extension `<Button Text="{i18n:Translate Text=AddButton}" />`